# How to clear a text input on focus but still be able to type? Flash/AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am trying to create a user input in an SWF and I want to clear the default text on focus but still allow the user to type into the input.

Currently I am using the following AS2 code:

```
input.zip.onSetFocus = function() {
    input.zip.text = "";
}
```

This clears the text as expected, but once the text is cleared, I cannot type anything into the input. If I remove the code, I can type in the input just fine.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're either continuously setting the text to empty... or by setting to text once, you're changing the type. This code snippet should resolve both issues.

```
//store this boolean somewhere
var hadFocus = false;
input.zip.onSetFocus = function() {
    if(!hadFocus){
        input.zip.text = "";
        input.zip.type = "input";
        hadFocus = true;
    }
}
input.zip.onKillFocus = function() {
    hadFocus = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It ended up being related to the custom font I was embedding. For some reason it wouldn't work, even with the font embedded. I changed it to "use device fonts" and now everything is working as expected.